# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")

Tags: java, database, security, glassfish

Again I have to face this error.

```
Fri Sep 16 17:17:29 CEST 2016 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.optional.DerbyControl.invokeNetworkServerControl(DerbyControl.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.optional.DerbyControl.main(DerbyControl.java:245)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.optional.DerbyControl.invokeNetworkServerControl(DerbyControl.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.optional.DerbyControl.main(DerbyControl.java:245)
```

This time I couldn't solve the issue editing the java.policy file.

Result of java -version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I found java.policy files in

```
/etc/java-8-openjdk/security
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/security
```

both of them with the row:

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen,resolve";
```

My machine is Linux 16.04.01 and the server is Glassfish4

Are there other possible places where to edit java.policy file?
Are there other possible causes?

Answer (score 8):

First, run the derby batch file sysinfo.bat to determine which JDK/JRE is being used to run it. If you are unable to pin point it, go to your computer's environment variables and check the value of `JAVA_HOME` .

Then go to that JDK/JRE's `\jre\lib\security` folder and add this:

```
grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen";
};
```

Comment: I tried with the files I found in ~/glassfish4/glassifish/javadb/. Is it correct? Running sysinfo.bat (isn't it only for windows machine? I have a linux machine) I get errors. Running sysinf I get the error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo. Running "echo $JAVA_HOME" I get nothing :-(

Comment: Granting permissions to all code ever run by an installation of the JRE probably isn't a great idea.

Comment: True. But since it is a listen on a given port - the default derby port - and if your machine is behind a firewall, it wouldn't be too dangerous. But i do accept your point.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beabx.html :

Each GlassFish Server domain has its own global J2SE policy file, located in domain-dir/config. The file is named server.policy.

Comment: Thanks for having pointed out. I didn't know. But my problem autonomously solved simply restarting the server. Difficult to say what was the reason